# How to open a URL attached task edit form to email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow

Anyone who has attached task edit form URL to email to open task edit form for Assign Task Process action with multiple Approvers in SharePoint 2013 list workflow? Thanks

Comment: are to trying to show a link for Task Approval form in your Email ??

Comment: @Rohit,  Edit mode form

Answer (score 0):

You can get the link of Task form using `Current Task:Form_URN`.

Refer below Image:

[image]

Comment: Hey Rohit, Could you try using SharePoint 2013. I tried , but I don't see Current task. Need help

Comment: the user wants this in sp 2013 designer not in 2010. The above works in 2013

Comment: Only works for `Start Custom Task Process Action` with 2010 Sharepoint workflows.