# How can URL attached task list (Edited)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow

Anyone who has attached task edit form URL to email to open task edit form for Assign Task Process action with multiple Approvers in SharePoint 2013 list workflow? Thanks

NB:
1- My Environment is SharePoint 2013 on prem

2- [Previous Question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223278/how-to-open-a-url-attached-task-edit-form-to-email)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For "Assign Task Process Action", Use Task Url property:**

[image]

**For "Start Custom Task Process Action", Use Form URN property:**

Use Form URN Property on Current task to get task edit form URL. You have to edit the task process to access task properties.

**1. First Click on Your Task:**

[image]

**2. Change behaviour of single task :**

[image]

**3. Add Send Email Action in Task Pending Stage:**

[image]

**4. In Email body add hyperlink & set it to Form URN property**

[image]

Comment: Hey Vishal , I don't see Current task in SP 2013 data source ? need help

Comment: Which action are u using for creating task? Current task data source available for "Start custom task process" action.

Comment: If are u using "Assign task process" action then there is no current task data source. There is task properties data source

Comment: I use Assign task process.

Comment: Data source depends upon what  action u r using. In your case there will be "Task Properties" data source & "Task url" property.

Comment: I don't see Task Properties. In SP 2013 Workflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64060/discussion-between-sai-and-vishal).

Comment: Sai, I'm unable to login into chat. Facing problem while login. I'm not on PC, I am using mobile app. I don't have SharePoint & SP designer access right now. But I believe that the task properties data source must be available there. Edit the assign task process action and check under email options by editing the email body.

Comment: OR try to using "start custom task process" action.

Comment: @SPDeveloper This does not answer the question. Question was asked for 2013 for Task Edit form. You answered for 2013 Task Display form.